# Bounding a repeating, 2-dimensional path sequence

Tags: algorithm, graph

### Input

Given a string sequence of *n* characters, containing only:

- "G" - Go, move in present direction
- "L" - Turn present direction left
- "R" - Turn present direction right

### Output

If one executed the sequence an infinite number of times, return `true` iff the drawn figure can be bound by a circle of finite radius; otherwise; return `false`.

### My attempt

I thought (just based on a couple examples and attempting to recognize a pattern) that the significant metric would be the count of movement to the left and to the right.

I hypothesized that equal left and right movements would be indicative of a non-contained sequence; I highly doubt this is correct because I'm unsure how this would handle movement without change of direction? i.e. *"RGG"* of *"LGRGG"*.

Unfortunately, I got stuck in the implementation. The following is my attempt in psuedo-code:

```
def isBounded(string sequence) {
    commands = list{}
    directionStack = stack{}
    directionStack.push(findReverse(sequence, [](char a){ a != 'G' })) // search for the last direction command

    for c in sequence {
        if c == 'G' {
            commands.append(directionStack.pop())
        } else {
            directionStack.push(c)
        }
    }

    lefts = commands.count('L')
    rights = commands.count('R')
    return lefts != rights
}
```

I don't think this is correct for something like:

- *RGLGRGG*
- *GRGLGLGLG*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is easily proven using simple linear algebra on cartesian plane.

## Answer

The resulting path *`p`* of a infinitely repeated finite sequence *`s`* is always bounded, unless the difference in turns (defined as: `diff=|leftTurns - rightTurns|`) is a multiple of 4 and the end position of *`s`* is not equal to the start position.

---

## Proof

#### **Case 1**: `diff % 4 == 0` <==> terminates facing initial direction

- **Ends at starting position `(0,0)`** ==> **bounded**, each iteration will always return to (0,0) along a finite path.
- **Ends at `(x,y) != (0,0)`** ==> **unbounded**, each progressive iteration `n+1` will move to position `P(n+1) = P(n) + (x,y)` or `P(n) = n * (x,y)`. As `n->inf` so follows `P(n)->inf`.

#### **Case 2**: `diff % 4 == 1` <==> terminate facing 1 rotation left/right of initial direction

For the sake of simplicity we will **assume 1 more left than right**. Or a counter-clockwise 90 degree turn.

**Iteration:** (start position) -> (end position)

1. `(0,0)` -> `(x,y)`

   In the next iteration we will be travelling the same distance but in the left rotated direction. So using the corresponding transform matrix, our update vector is:

   [image]
2. `(x,y)` -> `(x - y,y + x)`

   Our update vector has been rotated to the left yet again and so:

   [image]
3. `(x - y,y + x)` -> `(-y, x)`

   And again a rotation of our update vector:

   [image]
4. `(-y, x)` -> `(0,0)`

   Finally, we have arrived at our starting location, and are facing our initial direction:

   [image]

#### **Case 3**: `diff % 4 == 2` <==> terminates facing 2 rotations left/right of initial direction

**Iteration:** (start position) -> (end position):

1. `(0,0)` -> `(x,y)`

   Two 90 degree rotations:

   1: [image]

   2: [image]
2. `(x,y)` -> `(0,0)`

   Returning to the starting position facing the initial direction.

#### **Case 4**: `diff % 4 == 3` <==> terminate facing 3 rotations left/right of initial direction

Equivalent proof to a single rotation left/right (see Case 2.)

Answer (score 0):

The shape can be bound if start point is the same as end point, no matter from what direction the end point reached. It is not hard to implement an algorithm which 'plays' sequence of G, L, R and checks if end point equals to the start point. Sorry for my haskell:

```
move ((x,y),(dx,dy)) 'G' = ((x+dx,y+dy),(dx,dy))
move ((x,y),(dx,dy)) 'R' = ((x,y), (dy,-dx))
move ((x,y),(dx,dy)) 'L' = ((x,y), (-dy,dx))

play start [] = start
play start (x:xs) = play (move start x) xs

canBound sequence = (fst $ play (start,direction) sequence) == start where
    start = (0,0)
    direction = (0,1)
```

~

Comment: Consider: `RGLGLG`. On the 0th iter (0,0), 1st iter (0,1), 2nd iter (-1,1), 3rd iter (-1,0), 4th iter (0,0). So it take 4 iters to return to it's starting position and direction. So using this method you could potentially have to play out any number of iterations, and in the event it isn't bounded... you just play it out forever.

Comment: You're right, my approach does not take into account such cases. I was thinking about such cases and as far as I see there are bound figures of three types: 1. Gets closed in one go, like GRGRGRG ; 2. Gets closed in two goes GRGR; 3. Gets closed in 4 goes like RGLGLG. I could not imagine another cases, but I cannot prove they does not exist. So I would adapt my procedure by passing it sequence taken 4 times: GRGR -> GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGR. Calculation still takes O(n), so I don't see problem here.

Comment: That's so much. I think I've worked out a solution and proof. It affirms your suspicion about a maximum of four iterations to return to start position+direction (if ever). I'll post it later today.

Comment: Posted the proof. Let me know if you catch any missed cases/errors.